# Joomla pagination loop without start or end

Tags: navigation, pagination

How can I achieve loop pagination?
Lets say I have 5 articles, Im adding pagination and on the 1-st page I have "next" button, on pages 2-4 I have both "next" and "prev" buttons, on the last 5-th page I will have only "prev" button. How Can I have "next" and "prev" buttons both on every page? So after reaching 5-th page and pressing "next" Im going to 1-st page, like loop or circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article pagination is handled by a content plugin called `pagenavigation`, located in `ROOT/plugins/content/pagenavigation`. The problem is that although [Joomla allows for plugin overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla#Plugin_Alternative_Layouts_.28overriding_a_plugin.29), most plugins don't support it, including this particular plugin. Either way, the code you have to change is in `pagenavigation.php` in the aforementioned folder (at aprox. line #174):

Change the existing code:

```
        if ($location - 1 >= 0)
        {
            // The previous content item cannot be in the array position -1.
            $row->prev = $rows[$location - 1];
        }

        if (($location + 1) < count($rows))
        {
            // The next content item cannot be in an array position greater than the number of array postions.
            $row->next = $rows[$location + 1];
        }
```

**With this:**

```
        if ($location - 1 >= 0)
        {
            // The previous content item cannot be in the array position -1.
            $row->prev = $rows[$location - 1];
        } else {
            // Add button to return to last element
            $row->prev = $rows[count($rows)-1];
        }

        if (($location + 1) < count($rows))
        {
            // The next content item cannot be in an array position greater than the number of array postions.
            $row->next = $rows[$location + 1];
        } else {
            // Add button to return to start
            $row->next = $rows[0];
        }
```

As far as I know, you have three ways to solve this:

1. Edit the original file, as above. This is called a core hack, and not recommended, because your edits might be overwritten when you update Joomla.
2. Create a new plugin based on the existing `plg_pagenavigation`, and apply the edits. Then publish your new plugin and unpublish `pagenavigation`.
3. Make the plugin compatible with plugin overrides by adding this code to `ROOT/plugins/content/pagenavigation/pagenavigation.php`, right after `defined('_JEXEC') or die;`:

   ```
   $chromePath = JPATH_THEMES . '/' . JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate() . '/html/pagenavigation.php';
   if (file_exists($chromePath))
   require_once ($chromePath);

   if (!function_exists('plgContentNavigation')) {
     function plgContentNavigation( &$row, &$params, $page=0 )
     {
   ```

   Then this at the end of the file:

   ```
    }
   }
   ```

   This will make Joomla look for the file `ROOT/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/pagenavigation.php` and use it as override if it exists. It's still a core hack, but it might be easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes, it is working!
Thank you so much for helping me out.

Cheers